# Can nginx proxy_cache replace fastcgi_cache?

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi

If nginx is already used with `proxy_cache`, is there still any need to use `fastcgi_cache`?

In other words.. When using nginx `proxy_cache`, there is no more need for `fastcgi_cache`?

Comment: The opposite is also true, and in fact FastCGI caching has become more popular in the last several years and will likely continue to be in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The caching mechanism is the same. The difference is that you must use `proxy_cache` directives if you are `proxy_pass`ing to a backend app, and you must use `fastcgi_cache` when you `fastcgi_pass` to a backend app.